# class ChecklistViewController has no initialiser?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

When I try to run my app it suddenly shows the error of class has no initialisers. Tell me whether their is any code problem or a variable declaration problems.Can anyone tells me the reason behind this error.

```
import UIKit
class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController {

    var row0item: ChecklistItem
    var row1item: ChecklistItem
    var row2item: ChecklistItem
    var row3item: ChecklistItem
    var row4item: ChecklistItem

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int

    {
        return 5

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell

    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem")

        let label = cell!.viewWithTag(1000) as!UILabel



        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            label.text = row0item.text

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            label.text = row1item.text

        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

            label.text = row2item.text

        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

            label.text = row3item.text

        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            label.text = row4item.text

        }

        configureCheckmarkForCell(cell!, indexPath: indexPath)

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {


            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                row0item.checked = !row0item.checked

            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                row1item.checked = !row1item.checked

            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                row2item.checked = !row2item.checked

            } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
                row3item.checked = !row3item.checked
            } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
                row4item.checked = !row4item.checked

            }
            configureCheckmarkForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

        }
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func configureCheckmarkForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var isChecked = false

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            isChecked = row0item.checked
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            isChecked = row1item.checked
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

            isChecked = row2item.checked
        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

            isChecked = row3item.checked
        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            isChecked = row4item.checked
        }

        if isChecked {

            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {

            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a problem with your variable declaration.
If you declare variables as not optional (as you did), you have to initialize them in **override init()**.
If you declare them as optional you don't have to initialize them:

```
var row0item: ChecklistItem?
var row1item: ChecklistItem?
var row2item: ChecklistItem?
var row3item: ChecklistItem?
var row4item: ChecklistItem?
```

To access a row item:

```
row0item!.aPropertyOrFunction
```